# Page Layouts : 1 column , 2 columns-left , 2 columns-right , 3 column

Tags: magento2

I am having a doubt.

- What is mean by 1 column, 2 columns-left, 2 columns-right and 3 columns ?
- What is the use ?
- How we can identify this page is 1 column , or 2 columns-left or 2 columns-right or 3 columns ?
- Can anyone please explain in brief ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

**Page layout**

- Page layout declares the **wireframe** of a page inside the `<body>`
  section, for example `one-column` layout or `two-column` layout.
- The example below showed the standard  tag with the layout
  directive, which indicates the **structure** (type) of the page layout
  from which the new page layout is inherited.
- It means that module page with this layout file will have a
  `one-column grid`, the same that is used by the standard Magento 2
  “Luma” theme on the main page.
- I would like to remind that you can also use the admin panel to
  select the required template. The corresponding menu item can be
  found in the following way:

> Content ⇒  Pages ⇒ Target_Page_Edit ⇒ Design ⇒ Layout

If you apply a standard grid to the “Luma” theme main page.

[image]

**Where are the existing page layouts used in Magento 2?**

> There are 5 types of default page layouts in Magento 2.  Let’s take
>   the “Luma” theme as an example and see which main pages they are
>   applied at.

- `empty` (page without containers) – checkout pages (update from empty),
- `1 column` (one container for all the content) – home page,
  product-view, all-cms-pages, cart, login-page, success page,
- `2 column` with left bar (container for content and left sidebar) –
  what-is-new, category-view, subcategory-view, account-pages,
- `2 column with right bar` (container for content and right sidebar) –
  no-route-page (404),
- `3 column` (3 optional containers).

**Sample page layout:**

> /view/frontend/page_layout/2columns-left.xml

```
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <update handle="1column"/>
    <referenceContainer name="columns">
        <container name="div.sidebar.main" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="sidebar sidebar-main" after="main">
            <container name="sidebar.main" as="sidebar_main" label="Sidebar Main"/>
        </container>
        <container name="div.sidebar.additional" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="sidebar sidebar-additional" after="div.sidebar.main">
            <container name="sidebar.additional" as="sidebar_additional" label="Sidebar Additional"/>
        </container>
    </referenceContainer>
</layout>
```

**Page layout files conventional location**
Conventionally page layouts must be located as follows

- **Module page layouts**: `<module_dir>/view/frontend/page_layout`
- **Theme page layouts**: `<theme_dir>/<Namespace>_<Module>/page_layout`

**Refrences**

1. **[Magento DevDocs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-types.html)**
2. **[belvg](https://belvg.com/blog/working-with-block-templates-root-templates-empty-xml-and-page_layout-in-m2.html)**

Comment: Anytime, If it solves your query then you can mark solution as accepted which will help future readers.

Comment: what is the use of <update handle="1column"/> update handle?

Comment: The update handle is basically a "merge this layout with my current layout".

Comment: Thank you. one more thing , can you please explain me brief  in Ajax in magento2

Comment: sure, you are aware about normal AJAX right ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92814/discussion-between-aaditya-and-priya).

Answer (score 2):

You can read layout image via devdocs: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-overview.html

To use that column via layout, you can add attribute "layout" via your layout:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
```

Answer (score 2):

I am trying to answer in my perspective

layout in nothing but an view layer in magento 2. What you see in webpage is an layout and it can be like

> 1 - column, 2- coulmns-left etc..,

it will be defined in layout.xml respective to the pages you're working on.

For example :

If you're working on **homepage** then you must defining the layout in cms_index_index.xml likewise it varies from product page catalog_product_view.xml

and coming back to the question

**1 - Column**

[image]

**2 - column left**
[image]

**2 - column right** - is vise-versa of 2 - column left

and

**3 - column**

[image]

2 . How to identify layout of particular page

In magento you can inspect the page and check the body tag for layout class

It looks like

```
page-layout-1column or page-layout-2columns-left
```

and it does vary from page to page.

In magento you can verify by checking the xml file and for each page there will separate layout will be defined.

> Home page - cms_index_index.xml
>
> Cateogry Page - catalog_category_view.xml
>
> Product Page - catalog_product_view.xml
>
> Cart page - checkout_cart_index.xml
>
> Checkout - checkout_index_index.xml

and for cms pages you have login to admin and find out the layout in specific to pages.

For more information [visit here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-types.html)

Hope this information helps.

Answer (score 0):

Using the layout="" attribute with the desired layout worked for me.

```
layout="2columns-left"
```

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
```

After adding the attribute I ran these following commands via cli:

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento cache:clean
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```